# Probability, rolling a dice

Tags: probability

We roll a dice 10 times. What is a probability of obtaining a 6 in a first roll (event A) if we obtain 6 in all next 9 rolls (event B). 
Is it that simple that $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{1}{6}$? This excersise is in the part about Bernoulli scheme, so I'm wondering if I'm doing it right...

Comment: Yes, it’s that simple: the first roll does not depend in any way on the other rolls.

Comment: Assuming independence of rolls: yes, the probability to roll 6 is $\frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those events are following one another and are independent, therefore the probability of getting a 6 for the first roll is $\frac{1}{6}$.